# Another possible loophole in the audit system?

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits

I just started reviewing the First Posts queue when *I* had this come up,

> [image]

Now first of all I noticed the OP was deleted (no problem I've seen that before), but looking more closely I also noticed the user has no name, which I thought was strange since all the deleted users I've ever seen either had kept their chosen name or were assigned their default name (e.g, "user123456").

And then as I was typing up this post I double checked the link to that review (expecting it to show me the screenshot, since I hadn't yet reviewed it) and it lead me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5202943). The same review, but reviewed by someone else (at that point I realised it was an audit).

Is this a true loophole (bug)? Or is the system deliberately made this way?

Comment: @Payeli Well it seems like a clear indication to robo-reviewers when an audit is in front of them, not a good idea.

Comment: @Payeli Nope, that would just annoy me and every other decent reviewer. This problem can easily be solved by changing the OP name and avatar to a randomly picked (non-deleted) user.

Comment: Until that randomly picked (non-deleted) user is someone like Jon Skeet.

Comment: @JonK Good point, well I didn't post that comment as a *complete* solution to the problem; as the issue with waiting a few mins for someone else to review the audit isn't solved by that suggestion. Anyway, the picking algorithm could be fixed by randomly picking users between `X` and `Y` rep (say 100 - 10,000 as an example).

Comment: It sounds like it would be easier to just do away with the username completely. Just have some placeholder text saying something like "A StackOverflow User"?

Comment: @JonK Yeah, or that I guess. At least it's more simple to implement. I suppose the "waiting 'n' check" issue could be solved by assigning said audit to that user, so *only* that user can review it.

Comment: You **paid attention** and noticed discrepancies. Congratulations, the system *works*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Arguable I'd say. He paid enough attention to notice that it was an audit. From there you can work out what you need to do to pass without really thinking about it. I would have thought the ideal system audited your actions in such a way that you *didn't realise* you were being audited until after the event. Being able to notice it's an audit before it's done defeats that...

Comment: @Sam: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170683/stop-using-real-accounts-in-suggested-edit-audits for the consequences of borrowing real users' identities (and note some users, including myself, are dissatisfied with the resolution).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I see, well as JonK suggested we could say "A Stack Overflow user" or just remove the name and avatar all together.